# Meaning of "out" in this context

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, adverbs

In a text I found:

> .... like the other giant planets Uranus has a ring system and numerous moons. It is the seventh planet **out** and it ......

Is the **out** is adverb here? Give some examples and explain.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

> They live ten miles out (from us).
>   They live ten miles away from us.
>   They live ten miles out (from the place mentioned before).
>
> It is the seventh planet out (from the sun).
>   It is the seventh planet away from the sun.

Here, *out* is an adverb and it means *away from a place; at a distance from a place*.